Opening a PDF in a Blob Instead of a PDF Preview Component
I'm currently using BlobProvider to open a PDF document in a new tab as a blob. Here’s the code snippet I’m using:
<BlobProvider document={<OrderDocument data={orderData} />}> {({ url, ...rest }) => { return ( <a href={url} target="_blank"> <BsPrinter className="size-6 text-primary-dark-light" /> </a> ); }} </BlobProvider>

but now I want to open the pdf from link after getting data from link, and open it in blob not in pdfPreview component like the example bellow:
import { OrderDocument } from '@/components'
import { toast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast'
import { useAuthContext } from '@/context/authContext'
import { getFetch } from '@/hooks/fetchData'
import { PDFViewer } from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ImSpinner6 } from "react-icons/im";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const OrderReceipt = () => {
    const { orderId } = useParams()
    const { user } = useAuthContext()
    const token = user?.apikey?.token

    const [orderData, setOrderData] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(null);

    const navigate = useNavigate()
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        getFetch(token, /orders/${orderId})
            .then((res) => {
                setOrderData(res.data?.data)
            })

            .catch((e) => {
                setIsError(e?.response?.data?.message)
                toast({
                    variant: 'destructive',
                    description: e.response.data.message,
                });
                navigate('/')
            })
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
    }, [])

    if (isLoading) {
        return <div className='w-full h-screen flex-center'>
            <ImSpinner6 className="animate-spin text-gray-500  size-24" />
        </div>
    }
    if (isError) {
        return <div className='w-full h-screen flex-center'>
            <h2>unexpected error</h2>
        </div>
    }

    return <PDFViewer style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh' }}>
        <OrderDocument
            data={[orderData]}
        />
    </PDFViewer>

}

export default OrderReceipt


What I Need:
I would like to open the PDF in the current window as a blob after getting the data, instead of using the PDFViewer component. How can I achieve this?
Additional Context:
The goal is to replace the PDFViewer component with functionality that opens the PDF in the browser's current tab as a blob.

To display PDF files received as base64 data from an API, you can use the following approach. Define a fileViewer function as shown below. By calling this function with the base64 data, the desired file name, and the MIME type, you can open and view the PDF in a new tab without needing any additional components.
export const fileViewer = (fileData: string, fileName: string, type?: any) => {
  const blob = b64toBlob(fileData, type)
  const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  window.open(blobUrl, '_blank')
}

  useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        getFetch(token, /orders/${orderId})
            .then((res) => {
                fileViewer(res.data?.data,thefileNameYouWant,'application/pdf')
            })

            .catch((e) => {
                setIsError(e?.response?.data?.message)
                toast({
                    variant: 'destructive',
                    description: e.response.data.message,
                });
                navigate('/')
            })
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
    }, [])
}

